# Displaying time exceeded (Timer) on Android Studio using Firebase?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

My question might be bit confusing, but what I basically want to do is,

I want to display the time exceeded for each item in the list when the start button on each item is clicked.

For example, suppose I have a listView of items that has a time and a button

`TIME` `START`

`TIME` `START`

`TIME` `START`

When I click the start button, the TIME textView should start a timer that increments every 1 minute and stops when it reaches a specific minute).

Since I am using the Firebase realtime database as my DB, I was thinking of incrementing 1 to the `Time` data every 1 minute.

What is a good approach of doing this?

Comment: Use count down timer from here https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html Or google online for further uses of android count down timer.

Comment: will this still work even if the app is off?

Comment: but for displaying time use count down timer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can update a value in Firebase Realtime Database either on client side or either on server side by using [Cloud Functions for Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/).

You can write a function that updates that particular value every 10 minutes. The benefit of using Cloud Functions rather then the first option is that will still work even if the application is offline. This is the best practice.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. My question is, is it okay (or is it a valid practice) to update the Real Time database every minute for this kind of task?

Comment: It depends on your app requirements. But knowing that updating on client side might cause problems, that's your only choice. As far as i tested in one of my application, i can say that it won't be a problem.